How to detect if any modal <dialog> is open?
I have a page with multiple <dialog> elements, which I open as modal using their showModal() methods.
I want to detect whether any of them is currently opened from Javascript (since some event handlers shouldn't trigger when a modal is opened). Is it possible to check if modal is currently opened? Maybe through existance of dialog::backdrop or checking someway for inertness of non-modal content?

Use HTMLDialogElement.open to test if open

@Blindman67 this way I can test for a single element. I want to know if any of them is opened as modal, preferably without iterating over them.

@RoryMcCrossan after searching a bit more, it turns out :modal pseudo-class can be used.

When dialog is opened as modal, it gets CSS pseudo-class :modal - so it can be queried with selector:
document.querySelector("dialog:modal") === null; // No dialog is opened as modal.
document.querySelector("dialog:modal") !== null; // Some dialog is opened as modal.


Good answer +1. Note that document.querySelectorAll("dialog:modal") will return a node list of all open modal dialogs in order that they are defined in the document (Not in opened order).
